# Json to Object not working

Tags: java, json, gson

I have this Json String:

```
{"type":"ContactSegment","x_e10_isTemplate":"false","x_e10_createdAt":"1408441893","x_e10_createdBy":"47","currentStatus":"Draft","id":"384","initialId":"-500023","createdAt":"1408441893","createdBy":"47","depth":"complete","folderId":"1567","name":"Untitled Segment delete me","permissions":[2,5,4,3],"updatedAt":"1408441893","updatedBy":"47","elements":[{"type":"ContactFilterSegmentElement","id":"629","initialId":"-500025","depth":"complete","count":"0","isIncluded":"true","lastCalculatedAt":"1408441893","filter":{"type":"ContactFilter","x_e10_isTemplate":"false","x_e10_createdAt":"1408441893","x_e10_createdBy":"47","currentStatus":"Draft","id":"100584","initialId":"-500024","createdAt":"1408441893","createdBy":"47","depth":"complete","folderId":"51","name":"Filter Criteria 1","permissions":[2,5,4,3],"updatedAt":"1408441893","updatedBy":"47","criteria":[{"type":"CampaignResponderCriterion","id":"1216","initialId":"-500026","activityRestriction":{"type":"NumericValueCondition","operator":"notLess","value":"1"},"timeRestriction":{"type":"DateValueCondition","operator":"withinLast","value":{"type":"RelativeDate","offset":"1","timePeriod":"day"}},"campaignIds":["313"]}],"scope":"local","statement":"1216"}}]}
```

I use GSON to convert JSON to Object:

```
ContactSegment segment = new ContactSegment();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    segment = gson.fromJson(response.body, ContactSegment.class);
```

This is the ContactSegment class:

```
public class ContactSegment {

public static String id;
}
```

When I try to do segment.id, it returns me null;

Comment: Should `id` really be static? (And why create a new `ContactSegment` only to reassign it later?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `id` being static,it belongs to the class,not an object. Try using it as a non-static member.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the id is static.